# Hibernate: prevent delete orphan when using merge();

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of object

```
@ManyToMany(Fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinTable(...inverseJoin....)
public list<objects> getList()
```

I might not want to initialize it when I execute dto.merge.

Hibernate will auto remove all the relationships, even I did not specify delete_orphan.

May I know how to prevent hibernate from deleting orphans aka relationship?

Currently I have to retrieve/set the list from DB before doing a merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is part of the entity state, since the entity is the owner of the association.

So if you merge a detached entity which doesn't have anything in the bean, you're telling Hibernate: here's the new state of the entity, which doesn't contain any object anymore. 
So obviously, Hibernate deletes the association between the entity and the objects previously contained in the list.

My guess is that you construct a new entity instance and pass it to `merge()`, instead of getting an entity from the session, modifying it, and then passing this instance to merge():

instead of doing:

```
SomeEntity e = new SomeEntity();
e.setId(34L);
e.setFoo("newFoo");
e = session.merge(e);
```

you should be doing:

```
SomeEntity e = session.get(SomeEntity.class, 34L);
e.setFoo("newFoo");
// if the entity is detached:
e = session.merge(e);
```

Note that your problem has nothing to do with deleting orphan. Delete orphan means: if I remove the association between paren and children, then the child entities themselves should be deleted automatically.

Comment: Changes are coming from the view layer is a Model and I have a dtoBuilder... how do I know which data have change? Is there a good design pattern to manage this kind of issues? Why doesn't hibernate provide a annotation to ignore the merge?