# Hibernate: Doman Model to JPA Entity/DTO & Merge() Design pattern or best practice

Tags: java, hibernate

The recommended way of using merge() is to first get the DTO first before inputting the changes.

```
public void merge(PersonModel model) {

Person inputDTO = PersonBuilder.build(model)

Person dto = get(pk)
dto.setName(inputDTO.getName())

dto.getChildren().clear()

Iterator<Child> iter = inputDTO .getChildren().Iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()){
   dto.getChildren().add(iter.next());
}

dto.merge();
```

}

Is there a more elegant way of performing such operation translating domain model to dto and merging it so that no data are accidentally deleted.

Example of problem: 
[Hibernate: prevent delete orphan when using merge();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098266/hibernate-prevent-delete-orphan-when-using-merge)

I find the need to clear the list and adding it very wasteful.

Can someone recommend me a design pattern or a way to code it properly?

Thank you

ADD ON:

1) Possible to use Hibernate Hashset to replace List? Will hibernate hashset replace elements base on primary keys?

any help?

Comment: It would be much clearer if you didn't use the term DTO to refer to a JPA entity.

Comment: Edited title... will edit content once I am back from work.

Comment: Is the relationship to Child @OneToMany, or is it a composite?

Comment: @wrschneider99 it shouldn't matter as it s dynamic. but the child relationship is a composite key.

Answer (score 3):

> "The recommended way of using merge() is to first get the DTO first before inputting the changes"

Who recommended you to do this?

> "Is there a more elegant way of performing such operation translating domain model to dto and merging it so that no data are accidentally deleted."

I don't think you can translate domain objects to DTOs. A DTO is just about data, a domain object is data, behaviour and context. Completely different.

If you don't have behaviour and context in your domain objects ([a.k.a. anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)), you don't need an extra DTO layer that just duplicates the objects.

Because you tagged this question with Hibernate and mentioned it in your question, you don't need to call merge yourself because you just got the object from the database and Hibernate will flush the session to synchronize the changes with the database.

> "Possible to use Hibernate Hashset to replace List? Will hibernate hashset replace elements base on primary keys?"

I would replace the List with a Hashset, since the table where the data is going to be stored is a set, not a list (you can't have duplicate records). A hashset will not replace elements based on primary keys. A set (any set, Hibernate's implementation is no different) works by preventing duplicates. It uses your equals() and getHashCode() implementation to find out if there is already an object in that set. If that is the case, it won't be added but it keeps the original.

Comment: Who recommended you to do this? >> See the link attached. My domain model is slightly different from my dot(There is a good reason) You mean hibernate will "auto" merge even I didn't use .update() or .merge().